# ActionScript 3.0 - Null Bytes in ByteArray

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I am trying to understand the significance of null bytes in a ByteArray. Do they act like a terminator? I mean, can we not write further into the ByteArray once a null byte has been written?

For instance,

```
import flash.utils.*;

public class print3r{
    public function print3r{
        Util.print(nullout());
    }

    public function nullout:ByteArray (){
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bytes.writeInt(((403705888 + 1) - 1)); // Non Printable Characters
        bytes.writeInt(((403705872 - 1) + 1)); // Non Printable Characters
        bytes.writeInt(0x18101000); // Notice the NullByte in this DWORD
        bytes.writeInt(0x41424344); // ASCII Characters ABCD
        return bytes;
    }
}

new print3r;
```

This gives a blank output.

Now, if I replace the DWORD, 0x18101000 with 0x18101010, this time I can see the ASCII padding, ABCD in the output.

My question is that, is it possible to write past the null byte into the ByteArray()?

The reason I ask is because I have seen in an ActionScript code, that a lot of writeInt and writeByte operations are performed on the ByteArray even after the null byte is written.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it possible to write past the null byte into the ByteArray()?

Of course it is. `ByteArray` -- is a chunk of raw data. You can write whatever you like there, and you can read in whatever way you like (using zero bytes as delimiters or whatever else you may want to do).

What you see when you send your bytes to standard output with `trace()`, depends solely on what you actually do with your data to convert it to a string. There are several ways of converting an array of bytes to string. So, your question is missing the explanation of what `Util.print()` method does.

Here are several options for converting bytes to a string:

- Loop through bytes and output characters, encoding is up to you.
- Read a string with [ByteArray.readUTFBytes()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/common/langref/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readUTFBytes%28%29). This method reads utf-encoded symbols; it stops when zero character is encountered.
- Read a string with [ByteArray.readUTF()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/common/langref/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readUTFBytes%28%29). This method expects your string to be prefixed with unsigned short indicating its length. In other terms it is the same as `ByteArray.readUTFBytes()`.
- Use [ByteArray.toString()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/common/langref/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#toString%28%29). This is what happens when you simply do `trace(byteArray);`. This method ignores zero bytes and outputs the rest. This method uses `System.useCodePage` setting to decide on the encoding, and can use UTF BOM if the data begins with it.

Here are some tests that illustrate the above:

```
var test:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

// latin (1 byte per character)
test.writeUTFBytes("ABC");

// zero byte
test.writeByte(0);

// cyrillic (2 bytes per character)
test.writeUTFBytes("\u0410\u0411\u0412");

trace(test); // ABCАБВ
trace(test.toString()); // ABCАБВ
test.position = 0;
trace(test.readUTFBytes(test.length)); // ABC

// simple loop
var output:String = "";
var byte:uint;
for (var i:uint = 0; i<test.length; i+=1) {
    byte = uint(test[i]);
    if (output.length && i%4 == 0) {
        output += " ";
    }
    output += (byte > 0xF ? "" : "0") + byte.toString(16);
}
trace(output); // 41424300 d090d091 d092
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try what you suggested and also look into the various functions provided for reading from a ByteArray. One question, I am using: http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/ to practice ActionScript. Doesn't it have support for trace()? Because I am unable to see the output using trace() in it.

Comment: No idea, actually. I think, it's better to practice with real-world tools. [Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html) is free (compiler + bunch of tools), and [Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) is free also (an IDE, that uses Flex SDK to compile ActionScript).

Comment: Thank you. I will check them out.

Comment: Here's an interesting one.  Suppose you fill a byte array with characters 0 through 127 and trace it.  The trace output displays nothing.  However, if you fill it instead with 0 through 128, then it displays all the characters!  It's like the null character throws off the display of the string if it contains only ascii characters 0 through 127, but as soon as the string includes a character 128 or above, it displays ok.  Try it: `import flash.utils.ByteArray; var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); for (var i:int = 0; i <= 127; i++) b.writeUTFBytes( String.fromCharCode( i ) ); trace(b.toString());`

Comment: I had the same problem reading ByteArray to string, where null-bytes terminated string I was processing. This answer with examples helped me to understand ByteArray, null-bytes and it's influence in string throughoutly.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a null to a byte array has no significance as far as I know. The print function might however use it as a string terminator.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. So, the problem was with the Print function. I need to use an alternative to read the output from a ByteArray with null bytes written in it.